# DIP Dimensional drawings: multiple values

Tags: dip

I am checking out for dual-inline packages for my application and I came across some products from Analog Devices and Texas Instruments with three different dimensions for each measurement.
Does that mean that these DIPs are available in three sizes, or these are the individual dimensions of each measurement in a single device size?[image: attached image from Texas Instruments DIP product]

Answer (score 3):

Those are the maximum, nominal and minimum values for each dimension. The variations are due to tolerances in manufacturing.